# How to use webex from Debian Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, webex, cisco-webex

Colleagues have scheduled an important presentation on webex with> 20 participants for tomorrow.

### Requirements

I get a message that my browser is not supported when I try the [webex test meeting](https://www.webex.com/test-meeting.html/). There seems to be 2 lists of requirements:

- The [webex meeting suite requirements](https://help.webex.com/en-us/nki3xrq/Webex-Meetings-Suite-System-Requirements) Firefox 32 bits only there.
- The list of [Web App Supported Operating Systems and Browsers](https://help.webex.com/en-us/9ehuwu/Web-App-Supported-Operating-Systems-and-Browsers). Firefox on linux appears there.
  I don't know which one applies to my meeting type?

### 32 bits Install instructions only

The only instructions from webex I found are these ones on help.webex.com: [How-can-I-Join-a-Meeting-Using-64-bit-Red-Hat-Linux-6](https://help.webex.com/en-us/WBX61986/How-can-I-Join-a-Meeting-Using-64-bit-Red-Hat-Linux-6).
The help page suggests installing the following:

- Download 32-bit Mozilla Firefox: http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox

  - Install 32-bit Mozilla Firefox
- Download 32-bit Adobe Flash tar.gz for Linux package: http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/
- Download Sun JRE Linux Self Extracting file: http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp
- Ensure the following i686 rpms are installed:
  alsa-lib.i686
  dbus-glib.i686
  glibc.i686
  gtk2-engines.i686
  gtk2.i686
  libcanberra-gtk2.i686
  libcurl.i686
  libXt.i686
  nss.i686
  PackageKit-gtk-module.i686
- etc...

I am very surprised that it still uses flash and so many 32 bits applications.
We are in 2020. Is there really no other way for me to listen to this webex presentation?

Answer (score 1):

*Webex does not officially support 64-bit Linux builds* is what [WebEx themselves says](https://help.webex.com/en-us/WBX61986/How-can-I-Join-a-Meeting-Using-64-bit-Red-Hat-Linux-6). A [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/webex/comments/dca4if/cisco_webex_no_longer_supports_linux_browser/) agrees with you. However, you very kindly found a superior solution, which I have added to a prior request over at https://askubuntu.com/a/1225076/197910 .

Comment: Thanks. I found [these instructions for 64 bit Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/mshkrebtan/407786e334847544b40e7d6a8a53d247) running over a 32 bit firefox install with Java and flash.

Comment: Paul, please turn those into an answer, as I am _very certain_ other folks will need it! TYVM!

Comment: that's very kind of you, no need to quote me in that answer on askubuntu. It was just an easy google search away. If you want to credit someone, credit the author of that gist: https://gist.github.com/mshkrebtan (he has a great blog by the way with an impressive linux sound system)

Answer (score 1):

I found [these instructions for 64 bit Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/mshkrebtan/407786e334847544b40e7d6a8a53d247) running over a 32 bit firefox install with Java and flash.

## [Update 2022]

Native install is not a good idea anymore. Use webex from Firefox or chromium.

- A test Webex meeting is available at https://www.webex.com/test-meeting.html.
- Firefox [WebRTC Test Landing
  Page](https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/index.html) can be used to test if video capture and streaming are working from Firefox. (Seen on [this
  forum](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/share-screen-on-cisco-webex-using-firefox/13689/3)).